# Explicit Messaging on Ethernet/IP via Lua Sockets - How To?

Tags: sockets, tcp, lua, ethernet, industrial

Anyone have any experience in using Lua sockets to communicate with an industrial Ethernet/IP device using class 3 explicit messaging?

I'm looking to query data on a polled basis from an industrial servo drive from a piece of computer software that supports Lua 5.1 scripting. I see that Lua Sockets is available, but I'm unsure where to start with programming this interface.

Currently researching what is out there. Too new to understand what to try at the moment.

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably not a good place to start when your question contains some variant of "I don't know where to start" you are better off looking for a tutorial or learning more about the language/environment you want to work with. Come to Stackoverflow with a specific problem where you have code to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter which language/stack/technology you use as long as you have a TCP socket you should be able to achieve this in any environment.

CIP Class 3 is somewhat hard since you need to hand-roll your ForwardOpen/ForwardClose for connection establishment and graceful closing. Once you have a connection opened, you need to send an explicit messaging request over that connection.

I would try to find a FOSS lib to achieve this, play around with it, then dissect it, and put it on your LUA socket.

Sounds like fun to me